# Django - MongoDB: (could not connect to localhost:27017) Connection refused

Tags: django, mongodb

I am having issues getting mongodb working with Django, my setup is Mac OS X 10.7. I followed the tutorial available here: http://django-mongodb.org/topics/setup.html . I have tried with both virtualenv and without (this is my first time installing django so I shouldn't have any conflicts).

In settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
   'default' : {
      'ENGINE' : 'django_mongodb_engine',
      'NAME' : 'my_database'
   }
}
```

In firstapp.models.py

```
from django.db import models
from djangotoolbox.fields import ListField

class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    text = models.TextField()
    tags = ListField()
    comments = ListField()
```

In my shell (python manage.py shell), I try running:

```
from mydjango.firstapp.models import Post
post = Post.objects.create();
```

But I keep getting the following: **DatabaseError: could not connect to localhost:27017: [Errno 61] Connection refused** ([full traceback](http://pastebin.com/QEvvfSAd))

If I switch settings.py to the following:

```
DATABASES = {  
    'default': {  
        'ENGINE': 'django_mongodb_engine',  
        'NAME': 'my_database',  
        'USER': '',  
        'PASSWORD': '',  
        'HOST': 'localhost',  
        'PORT': '27017',  
        'SUPPORTS_TRANSACTIONS': False,  
    },  
}
```

I get this error in the shell: **ImproperlyConfigured: port must be an instance of int**

Comment: Are you actually running a MongoDB instance on `localhost`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you setup MongoDB separately? The howto you link doesn't seem to go over the MongoDB configuration. It assumes the database is already running. In any case MongoDB seems down, or is at least listening somewhere else.

The last error ("...instance of int") is just because you specified `'27017'` (a string) instead of `27017` in the configuration dictionary. But even then it should be equivalent to the first, simpler configuration.

Answer (score 0):

In case MongoDB is running but you still get this error while trying to connect from another machine, it may be due to Firewall running on the MongoDB server. 

I was running into this exact same error on CentOS 6.5 running MongoDB 2.6.0. Disabling firewall on the machine resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

## If you are creating models at models.py then there is an example below

models.py

```
from mongoengine import *

class UserLocation(Document):

    message = StringField(required=True, max_length=200)
```

You dont need the sqlite3 if you are not using it and only the mongodb then you have an optio to comment it

settings.py

```
# DATABASES = {
#             'default': {
#                     'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
#                     'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
#                 }
#             }
```

Now in

views.py

```
from .models import UserLocation

def save_function(request):

    msg = "shinto"

    # saving the data to the database
    data = UserLocation(message = msg)
    data.save()

    # reading the data
    read_data = json.loads(UserLocation.objects().to_json())

    print read_data
```

## There is also another method and its very simple (you don't need to create models in models.py)

views.py

```
from pymongo import MongoClient

client = MongoClient(port=27017)

db = client.testing_db # use a database called testing_db
collection = db.files # inside that db a collection called files

def a_new_function():


    fooman = {"name" : "shinto", "age" : 25}
    collection.insert(fooman)

    # if you need to display only the name "shinto
    #cursor = collection.find({"name" : "shinto"})

    # if you need to display all then empty
    cursor = collection.find({})

    for document in cursor:
        print(document)
```

## could not connect to localhost:27017 Connection refused or you see 111 is because you haven't either installed or opened mongodb in another terminal

For installation on ubuntu do the following

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 2930ADAE8CAF5059EE73BB4B58712A2291FA4AD5
```

if Ubuntu 12.04 (deprecated) then in terminal

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu precise/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

if Ubuntu 14.04 then in terminal

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu trusty/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

if Ubuntu 16.04 then in terminal

```
echo "deb [ arch=amd64,arm64 ] https://repo.mongodb.org/apt/ubuntu xenial/mongodb-org/3.6 multiverse" | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb-org-3.6.list
```

After do

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y mongodb-org
```

After installation then start mongodb

```
sudo service mongod start
```

To stop mongodb do

```
sudo service mongod stop
```

To restart mongodb

```
sudo service mongod restart
```

Finally you can use

```
mongo --host 127.0.0.1:27017
```

which will solve the issue

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

From your question it seems like you are trying to use Django with Mongodb. In which case why do you need Mongoengine?

The [official Mongodb](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/tools.html) documentation talks about [djongo](https://nesdis.github.io/djongo/). It works by translating SQL queries into query documents.

You don't need Mongoengine to run it.

All native Django contrib modules (eg. admin, user, session) work without any modification.

MongoEngine requires rewriting Django modules and last I checked, the native admin module didn't run on MongoEngine.

Your existing models run without any ORM translation as well.