# Adding and Querying to MongoDB from Django

Tags: django, mongodb

I am trying to build a DB system using Django as the framework and MongoDB for my database management system. How can I add things to a specific collection? Where should I specify the name of the collection?

Then, after I have added to the collection, how can I use a Django shell to ask for that information from Mongo?

Answer (score 0):

You don't "add a collection" on MongoDB -- you just use them. In [Django - MongoDB: (could not connect to localhost:27017) Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9510198/django-mongodb-could-not-connect-to-localhost27017-connection-refused) you already got Django MongoDB Engine running, so I don't understand your question? You can use the Django ORM to get data into and out of MongoDB now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many good tutorials of using mongodb with Django. One popular way is to use django-mongodb which integrates to django models. [Here](http://django-mongodb.org/tutorial.html) is their tutorial.

Another screencast: [Integrating mongoDB and Django](http://blog.montylounge.com/2010/02/11/integrating-mongodb-and-django/).